# Intellij IDEA doesn't work debug

Tags: intellij-idea, jboss7.x, jboss-weld

I have a problem with debug in IDEA. From particular moment when I try debug my web app on JBoss AS7 when I get row

```
Starting weld service for deployment
```

And debug not stop but nothing to get after this.

How I can resolve my problem?

Comment: What are you trying to debug? Are you running AS with idea's jboss plugin and do debug or how do you do it?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Seems problem in deploy-timeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find solution for my problem.

Debug->View Breakpoints->and Remove Method breakpoints